# Issue with black box appearing on Android app screen

Tags: android

Attached is a screen of my android app. It usually works perfect, but sometimes when I press an item on the menu, I get a small black box appearing (toast?).

Does anyone know why this occurs and how can I make it not appear again?

Here is the screenshot of the issue. 
http://postimg.org/image/eoe9vdqmd/

Comment: It looks like an empty `Toast`. Show us your code for that activity that is active in your screenshot please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want help, post relevant parts of your code, preferably in form of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The issue was that the Toast was empty. It is now solved.